# Como usar group by para agrupar resultados semelhantes para um mesmo registro da tabela?

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho um banco de dados com as tabelas: Contrato, contrato_corretor, contrato_comprador, contrato_vendedor, produto e safra.

Nesses relacionamento, um contrato terá obrigatoriamente somente 1 relacionamento com as tabelas produto e safra, 1 ou mais de um relacionamento com as tabelas contrato_comprador e contrato_vendedor(ou seja um contrato pode ter 1 ou mais compradores, e 1 ou mais vendedor), e nenhum ou apenas um relacionamento com a tabela contrato_corretor(o que faz com que um contrato pode ter ou nao um corretor).

Estou executando a seguinte query para que me retorne valores para preencher uma tabela num software java desktop.

```
select codigo,
case
when comprador.tipo_cliente = '0' then comprador.nome_empresarial 
when comprador.tipo_cliente = '1' then comprador.nome_fantasia
end as compradores,
case
when vendedor.tipo_cliente = '0' then vendedor.nome_empresarial 
when vendedor.tipo_cliente = '1' then vendedor.nome_fantasia
end as vendedores,
case
when corretor.tipo_cliente = '0' then corretor.nome_empresarial 
when corretor.tipo_cliente = '1' then corretor.nome_fantasia
end as corretores
from contrato ct
LEFT JOIN contrato_comprador on contrato_comprador.id_contrato = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cliente comprador on comprador.id_cliente = contrato_comprador.id_cliente

LEFT JOIN contrato_vendedor on contrato_vendedor.id_contrato = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cliente vendedor on vendedor.id_cliente = contrato_vendedor.id_cliente

LEFT JOIN contrato_corretor on contrato_corretor.id_contrato = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cliente corretor on corretor.id_cliente = contrato_corretor.id_cliente

;
```

Na imagem abaixo, vemos que o contrato 3512.5.7.4595 tem 1 comprador, 2 vendedores e 1 corretor, a partir daqui como posso proceder para agrupar todos os vendedores somente numa única linha na coluna vendedores?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 select codigo, quantidade, medida, pd.nome_produto,sf.descricao_safra, 
 sf.ano_plantio,
 sf.ano_colheita, valor_produto, valor_a_pagar, 

 GROUP_CONCAT(distinct
 case
 when comprador.tipo_cliente = '0' then comprador.nome_empresarial 
 when comprador.tipo_cliente = '1' then comprador.nome_fantasia
 end
 separator ',') as compradores,
 GROUP_CONCAT(distinct
 case
 when vendedor.tipo_cliente = '0' then vendedor.nome_empresarial 
 when vendedor.tipo_cliente = '1' then vendedor.nome_fantasia
 end
 separator ',') as vendedores,

 GROUP_CONCAT(distinct
 case
 when corretor.tipo_cliente = '0' then corretor.nome_empresarial 
 when corretor.tipo_cliente = '1' then corretor.nome_fantasia
 end
 separator ',') as corretores,
 ct.data_contrato, ct.status_contrato


from contrato ct
LEFT JOIN  safra sf on sf.id_safra = ct.id_safra
LEFT JOIN produto pd on pd.id_produto = sf.id_produto
LEFT JOIN contrato_comprador on contrato_comprador.id_contrato = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cliente comprador on comprador.id_cliente = 
contrato_comprador.id_cliente

LEFT JOIN contrato_vendedor on contrato_vendedor.id_contrato = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cliente vendedor on vendedor.id_cliente =         
contrato_vendedor.id_cliente

LEFT JOIN contrato_corretor on contrato_corretor.id_contrato = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cliente corretor on corretor.id_cliente =         
contrato_corretor.id_cliente
```

;

Comment: Avalie se o uso da função de agregação `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`, juntamente com a cláusula `GROUP BY`, atende a suas necessidades.

Comment: Obrigado por contribuir. Estou a tentar usar o group_concat. Nessa query eu usei o recurso de case para que, quando de acordo com o tipo do cliente ele pegue um dos camps(nome_fantasia para pj e nome_empresarial para pf) e use uma alias para identificar se e um vendedor, comprador ou corretor. Acontece que o group_concat não reconhece o alias como uma coluna valida, saberia me dizer o porquê? Outra coisa, eu nao poderia então, fazer desse select um sub query de outro select, e no 'select pai' usar o recurso de group_concat?

Comment: Editei o post e coloquei uma query, ela até funciona corretamente, mas não sei por qual motivo ela apenas retorna a primeiro contrato cadastrado no banco de dados, onde estou errando?

Comment: Experimente acrescentar o Group By no final